# Apply easing functions to Angular / Typescript auto scrolling function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scrolltop, autoscroll

For one of my apps I have written an auto-scrolling directive so that certain pages will scroll to anchor links when they are clicked rather than just immediately jumping to them (it also provides scroll-to-top functionality). It works great, except the motion is completely linear, there is no natural-feeling acceleration / deceleration. I would like to apply an easing function to the scroll movement so it feels more natural, but I am having trouble figuring out how to implement one. I think the solution would involve continuously re-calculating the increment as the page scrolls rather than just once at the beginning like I have it below, but so far my experiments with that have not been fruitful.

I'm sure someone else has already written a superior smooth-scrolling directive for Angular, but I'm interested in creating my own :-)

Anyone have any ideas?

```
   @HostBinding('scrollTop') scrollPos: number; // initialized when scroll command is first received

   private setIncrement(destPosition:number) : number { 
      let mod = (destPosition - this.scrollPos < 0) ? -1 : 1;   
      return mod*50;  
   }

   private scrollTo(position:number) : void { 
      this.inc = this.setIncrement(position);
      this.isScrolling = true;
      this.moveIt(this.scrollPos + this.inc);
   } 

   private moveIt(newPos:number) :void { 

      this.scrollPos = Math.min(newPos,this.bottomOfPage); 
      let diff = this.selectedAnchor.position - this.scrollPos; 
      let inView : boolean;

      // ... code that determines if anchor is in view and sets inView ...

      if ( inView || this.scrollPos >= (this.bottomOfPage)) {   
        // ... code that ends scrolling ...
      } 
      else { 
         this.timer = global.setTimeout(()=>{
            this.moveIt(this.scrollPos + this.inc);
         },1);
      }  
   }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://gizma.com/easing/

Comment: Oh yea good resource. I also found these - http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js   I've tried to incorporate a few of these into my own but no luck bc I'm not really sure what 'current time' would translate to in my implementation.